# JHipster gulp file error -- Task 'browserify' is not in your gulpfile

Tags: jhipster

In the JHipster gulpfile.js, there is a watch task set up for JS files which attempts to call a 'browserify' task.  However, there is no 'browserify' task defined. If you are running 'gulp server' during development, the process will terminate as soon as you modify one of your JS files.

```
[11:43:19] Server started
[11:43:19] LiveReload started on port 35729
[11:43:19] Finished 'server' after 52 ms
**[11:52:14] Task 'browserify' is not in your gulpfile**
[11:52:14] Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting
```

Is this a bug?  I don't see why we would need to call to browserify with the current setup.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it looks like a bug:https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/367
The Gulp option is a community effort, and is less stable than the Grunt option.
However, of course, our goal is to have a correct and stable Gulp option for our soon-to-be-released 1.0 version.
Can you add your comments and feedback to the opened bug?